# Quelles sont les durées des mots utilisés dans les expressions ?

Tags: expressions, étymologie

Voilà un bail que je me pose la question, sans savoir y répondre. Ça fait déjà une paye que je voulais la poser ici, mais je n'avais pas le temps. J'espère que je n'attendrai pas des lustres avant d'avoir la réponse.

Quelle est la durée d'un bail, une paye, un lustre, dans les expressions consacrées ?

Y a-t-il d'autres durées dans les expressions françaises ? Si oui, lesquelles ?

---

**edit**

Autres mots proposés dans les réponses :

- Pige
- Balais
- Plombe

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu parler d'une paye d'étudiant. Mais cela doit remonter aux calendes grecques.

Comment: Dans la Bible il y a plein d'expressions symboliques qui se rapportent au temps, et sont usitées encore aujourd'hui. (beaucoup d'évangéliques disent que c'est pas symbolique, mais réel). Par ex : 40 pour dire très longtemps (un peu comme notre "36"), avec les 40 jours du déluge, les 40 ans de déambulation des israélites dans le désert du sinaï ; il y a aussi 3, pour dire divin : les 3 jours entre la mort et la résurrection du christ, par ex. Tout cela vient peut ou prou des assyriens je crois.

Comment: Attention *balais* n'est utilisé que pour l'age!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ces termes désignent des durées précises, mais il faut noter que celles-ci ne sont pas pertinentes dans la plupart des cas où ils sont employés.

- Un lustre dure 5 ans. ([Source](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28Rome_antique%29))
- Une pige dure 1 an. ([Source](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=2011))
- Un balai dure 1 an. ([Source](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=5746))
- Une plombe dure 1 heure. ([Source](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=357))
- Une paye doit probablement valoir un mois (ou une semaine). C'est la durée depuis le versement du dernier salaire.
- Un bail doit probablement valoir plusieurs années, si on se réfère au secteur de l'immobilier.

Answer (score 2):

Pour ta première question, je ne sais pas s'il y a une durée précise concernant un bail, une paye, un lustre. Ces expressions traduisent en général une longue période.

Concernant ta deuxième question, il existe le mot "pige" qui désigne une année.

Answer (score 2):

On peut également penser à une éternité...
« Ça fait une éternité qu'on ne s'est pas vus. »

Il y a également l'expression un peu désuète « belle lurette » :
« Il y a belle lurette qu'ils se sont brouillés. »

En ce qui concerne l'étymologie, voici celle du [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/belle_lurette) :

> Locution créée par métanalyse de la locution il y a belle heurette (heurette étant un diminutif d’heure).

Answer (score 0):

Une des seules différences entre ces expressions est peut-être le contexte dans lequel elles sont utilisées.

Par exemple l'expression « J'attends son appel depuis des lustres » sera plus formel que de dire « J'attends son appel depuis un bail ».

D'ailleurs c'est peut-être uniquement mon cas mais je n'ai pas entendu les expressions « lustre » et « paye » depuis un moment (mis à part dans de vieux films).

Comment: Combien de temps ça dure un moment ? :-)

Comment: L'utilisation la plus typique de *bail* est : "ça fait un bail qu'on s'est pas vu", donc généralement plusieurs années bien que ça puisse désigner de durée plus courte par hyperbole.